# Effect of 8 shutdown SQL Server instances on memory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory, virtual-machines, low-memory

I've inherited a server that has 8 previously installed instances of SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition. The instance I am working with is SQL Server 2008 Express.

All of the Developer Edition instances are disabled as well as their corresponding SQLAgents. It was requested that nothing be uninstalled.

We have seen a memory error running DBCC CHECKDB on the new database:

> Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Check terminated. A failure was
>   detected while collecting facts.
>   Possibly tempdb out of space or a
>   system table is inconsistent. Check
>   previous errors. Msg 701, Level 17,
>   State 123, Line 1 There is
>   insufficient system memory in resource
>   pool 'internal' to run this query.

Could these previously installed instances affect memory usage of the active instance even though they are disabled?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Error posted. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No services/binaries running = no memory usage.

What DBCC errors did you get?

Comment: CheckDB failed: insufficient system memory in resource pool.

Answer (score 1):

If an app isn't running, it doesn't consume memory. But folks who do things like install 8 SQL instances likely screwed up all sorts of other stuff on the server.

Comment: Could the previously installed instances somehow affect the amount of memory the new instance was allocated on installation?

Comment: No, If not activated it does not run it does only comsume space... on the discs.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the max server memory was not reduced on each instance. See [Server Memory Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the max memory in your non-running instances is set to some high value, the instance you are currently working on may not be able to use all the memory. As Resmus said above you can reduce it or configure it so that SQL will allocate its memory requirments dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is memory handling related problem of your SQL Server 2008 instance and nothing related to shutdowned SQL 2005 instances.
Try add -g384 switch to SQL Server service startup parameters...